# Piping video from Raspberry Pi to Desktop running OpenCV

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for some hints.  I've got my Pi running OpenCV, but I'm about to take on a project which will need several IP cameras, all piping video to OpenCV.  I'm curious if it's possible to use the Pi+webcam in place of an IP camera?

I was attempting this by using Gstreamer on the Pi to pipe the video to a desktop PC, where I would use Python and OpenCV to process the images, then ship back answers to the Pi.  The Pi is connected to actuators, so the described setup would save me the purchase of a few ip cams.

I've setup ffmpeg to capture the video and stream it, I just can't seem to find an appropriate Gstreamer pipe to get it pulled up in OpenCV on the Desktop.

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, i strongly recommend the latest gestreamer code you can get to compile on the rpi.
some recent builds of gstreamer can be found in a 3rd party apt repository:

add

```
deb http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates/ . main
```

to

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

and run

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

as superuser.

hope that helps. if not you may find some useful info at
http://pi.gbaman.info/?p=150
http://sanjosetech.blogspot.de/2013/03/web-cam-streaming-from-raspberry-pi-to.html

or even https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the UV4L driver for the pi, this driver will enable an URL were you can see the pi camera so you can just process the images with cv2.videocapture("http://raspberrypi-ip/live") in this way you dont need to process anything on the pi as is very limited in comparition with your pc which will give you nice results.